# PHP - Can't access global array values between function calls

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to build a simple HTML form that is spread over three pages. First page asks for user's first and last name. Second page asks for his country & whether he would like to receive additional info. In the third page, all the info entered by the user is displayed

The first page has a single button named "Next" for going to the second page. The second page has two buttons named "Finish" to go the final page and "Back" to go back to the first page.

I am using a global array named "data" to hold the values entered by the user on each page.

Problem is, I can't access all array values in the final page. When I am trying to access the values, only the country selected in the second page is displayed. Neither the first name, nor the last name entered in the first page are displayed, even though I am storing those values in the array.

How can I display all the entered values on the final page ?

Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
        $data=array();
    ?>

    <?php
        if(!isset($_POST['next1']) && !isset($_POST['next2']) && !isset($_POST['back1']))
            Display1();
        else if(isset($_POST['next1']))
        {   
            global $data;
            array_push($data, $_POST['text1']);
            array_push($data, $_POST['text2']);
            Display2();
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['back1']))
        {
            Display1();
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['next2']))
        {
            global $data;
            $country=$_POST['country'];
            foreach($country as $x)
                array_push($data, $x);
            Display3();
        }
    ?>
    <?php
        function Display1()
        {
    ?>
    <form id="form1" action="Multi.php" method="post">
    <label>Enter First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="text1"  />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>Enter Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="text2"  />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="next1" value="Next" />
    <?php
    }

    function Display2()
    {
    ?>
        <form id="form2" action="Multi.php" method="post">
        Select Country
        <select name="country[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
        <option value="China">China</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="next2" value="Finish" />
        <input type="submit" name="back1" value="Back" />
    <?php
    }
    function Display3()
    {
        global $data;
        foreach($data as $x)
            echo $x . "<br>";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As soon as the page is loaded / sent to the browser, the `$data` variable is gone. You need either sessions or hidden fields to pass the values from the first page to the last page.

Comment: No, my previous question was different..

Comment: Please read the manual. All your questions are quite basic, and you would benefit by taking a day or so reading the manual. It will blow your mind. http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php

Comment: If this is so, then why has my question been down-voted ?

Answer (score 2):

Normal variables are not preserved between requests, the requests are independent from each other.

Either add all of them using hidden input fields (you can access them via `$_POST` then) or start a session using `session_start()` and save them in `$_SESSION`. Make sure to start the session at the very top, there must not be a single byte sent before!

Comment: Then what is the point of using global array if it can't preserve the values between function calls ?

Comment: @user10561 You can preserve it between *function calls*, but not between *independent requests*.

Answer (score -1):

For any variables declared outside of all functions use `$GLOBALS['data'];`
Hope that's what you're looking for.